# How does Auto-Linking libraries in C++ work?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker, comments, pragma

I am trying to auto-link following libraries. I've never used auto-linking feature and not sure how it works exactly. From my research this should work.  When I include the dll to the project besides the SDL libraries I get following errors: 
https://i.gyazo.com/e49a636ddad428fa48acdee78c930293.png

What are the steps to get Auto-linking working. Don't I need to specify some kind of path for this? Does it have to be in specific order?

This code is inside the DLL:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2main.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2_image.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2_mixer.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2_ttf.lib")
```

Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Comment: Please don't post images of text, especially *links* to images of text (links can go stale, making the question worthless). Instead  copy and paste the text, verbatim and without editing, into the question body. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explicitly specified what platform or development environment you're using, but it looks like you're using a recent version of Visual Studio. You need to configure the "VC++ Directories" settings in your project to include the paths for the lib files, under "Library Directories". These pragma directives will instruct the linker to search for the lib files in these directories.

Comment: Please do *not* edit the 'VC++ Directories'. use 'Configuration Properties / C\C++ / General / Additional Include Directories'.

Comment: Any particular reason why you feel one should not use the VC++ directories? Also, the field you suggested to use instead is for header includes, not library includes.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains that it can't find the *header* sdl.h, it hasn't gotten to the linking part (and I'm guessing it would have trouble there too).

To solve:

1. Add the path to the SDL headers here: project properties\ C/C++ \ General \Additional include directories
2. Add the path to your import libs here: project properties \ Linker \ General \ Additional Library directories.

Don't fiddle with 'VC++ directories' - as the name suggests, it is where the toolchain seeks various VC components (crt, mfc, open mp, windows sdk etc.). Messing this up could result in extremely hard to diagnose build failures.