# SDL Link Error when compiling basic program with header defined

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm following a lesson on C++ on Udemy and seem to have fallen at the first hurdle for creating the program.

I've added all of the SDL Header files and included SDL.H as the lessons indicate.

I've done nothing with the DLL files which where provided in the SDL Default download.

My code is as follows:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <iostream> 
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        cout << "SDL init failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "SDL Init succeeded" << endl;

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following errors upon compiling:

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _main   ParticleProjectNEW  ParticleProgram\ParticleProjectNEW\Source.obj   1

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function _main   ParticleProjectNEW  \ParticleProgram\ParticleProjectNEW\Source.obj  1

Comment: You need to link with the `.lib` file for SDL ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: ***I've done nothing with the DLL files which where provided in the SDL Default download.*** These have nothing to do with the current error but will eventulaly need to be in the same folder as your executable or you have to change your `PATH` environment variable to tell windows where to look for those dlls. Note that Debug and Relase will likely have different .dlls and different .lib files.

Comment: this answer might give you some ideas how to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008574/how-does-auto-linking-libraries-in-c-work

Comment: I've tried using the option from @marcinj and that didn't work.

Comment: I managed to find the problem that caused this... I had been using 64 bit version of SDL but was building in 32 bit (Or something along those lines...) therefore they where not identical.